# Why were the ancient men who had seen the 1st house weeping with a loud voice?

Tags: ezra

> [Ezra 3:12-13 KJV] 12 But many of the priests and Levites and chief of
> the fathers, [who were] ancient men, that had seen the first house,
> when the foundation of this house was laid before their eyes, wept
> with a loud voice; and many shouted aloud for joy: 13 So that the
> people could not discern the noise of the shout of joy from the noise
> of the weeping of the people: for the people shouted with a loud
> shout, and the noise was heard afar off.

Comment: Since scripture does not actually state the _reasons_ for the emotions, it remains opinion or . . . .  interpretation. The elder would have mixed reasons to weep and joy. The younger only had reason to rejoice.

Answer (score 2):

To begin, we need to be clear that the "house" here  is the House of the Lord, the foundations of which have just been re-laid (vs. 11) after many decades of disuse.

The older priests and Levites, who remembered the glory of the original Temple, wept aloud -- at first in sorrow for their many years of suffering while the Temple lay in destruction - and then for joy and relief. They, more than the rest, had mourned the loss of the Temple and they still repented for the nation's sins that had resulted in its destruction. Moreover, the Temple was the center of their daily lives and devotions. Now, at last, the altar had been restored and foundation of the Second Temple had been laid.

Just as loved ones weep when they are finally reunited after years of painful separation, the older priests and Levites wept at first because they remembered their pain and repented for the nation's sin. However, their sadness soon turned to joy that at last their beloved Temple would be restored and they could once again fulfill their purpose as priests in offering sacrifices to God.

Answer (score 0):

Ezra 3:12, 13 records mixed emotions at the laying of the foundation for rebuilding the temple.  There were good reasons for both sets of emotions:

**1. Joy**

Many were joyous that, at last, the temple reconstruction had begun.  This also meant that services and scarifies could re-start as well.  This was indeed a great occasion for celebration.  Recall that one of the main reasons that Judah went into captivity was it great sinfulness which resulted in the neglect of the temple services and their significance - this was not being rectified.

**2. Sadness and Weeping**

A few present on this occasion were old enough to recall Solomon's temple which lay before those present in ruins.  Thus, they were sad for the following reasons

- Solomon's temple was magnificent par-excellence - see its description in 2 Chron 3 & 4 - tons of gold and silver, ceder and polished stone (marble and granite?)
- The new temple that the Jewish returnees saw was a pathetic ruin and its reconstruction would never match the magnificence of the first.  Hence the weeping!
- They were also sad that when Solomon built the first temple there was a visible manifestation of the glory of the LORD, 2 Chron 7:1-3.  Nothing like this occurred on this occasion
- The new temple lacked a conspicuous object - the Ark of the Covenant which was lost forever.
- Further such aged people knew that they would not live long enough to see the project completed.  Here is another comment from the same time:

> Hag 2:2 - Who is left among you who saw this house in its former
> glory? How does it look to you now? Does it not appear to you like
> nothing in comparison?’

However, the prophet delivered a wonderful message about this project and its final glory which is obviously Messianic and gave great hope -

> Hag 2:9 - The latter glory of this house will be greater than the
> former, says the LORD of Hosts. And in this place I will provide
> peace, declares the LORD of Hosts.”

Jesus may have had this in mind when he said

> Matt 12:6 - But I tell you that something greater than the temple is
> here.

Thus, while no visible manifestation of the glory of the LORD was seen by Haggai, Zechariah and Zerubbabel, Jesus Himself actually graced the temple (500 years later) personally.